# Difference between AWS site-to-site VPN and Managed VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, vpn, aws-vpn

What is the difference between AWS Managed VPN and Site-to-site VPN

Answer (score 0):

A Site-to-Site VPN connection has the following limitations.
IPv6 traffic is not supported for VPN connections on a virtual private gateway.
An AWS VPN connection does not support Path MTU Discovery.

Take this in to consideration when using site to site

When connecting your VPCs to a common on-premises network, we recommend that you use non-overlapping CIDR blocks for your networks.